# Understanding WebHook and Azure Functions Usage

Tags: azure, webhooks, azure-functions

**What I Heard :**

**WebHooks :** They are just HTTP POST and not a new protocol or any new Technology . Let me put it in an example. Lets say we want to watch a directory for any changes and ping the user whenever anything is changed. I write a C# code watching the directory for changes and when something happens, I do an HTTP POST to let the user know something is changed and it might interest you.

**Azure Functions:** The best way i can explain you is hosting bits and pieces of reusable code online and hitting them via HTTP call whenever needed and not worrying about infrastructure or any supporting platform.

**What I want to know:**

Why is the name **WebHook** making so much noise , i mean its very clear and straight forward programming that you do to tell your users that something happened via some API calls or event listeners.

Can someone please make me understand these Terminologies if I got them in a wrong way and also some examples might help me along with your explanation.

Comment: Is it making such a noise then? Yes, it is a popular concept but that is about it. Due to its simplicity and use of existing tech it is widely supported.

Comment: yes @PeterBons , i understood that, but the thing that is worrying me is ,if you want to callback something to someone, you ping the destination whenever something happened as he expected or wanted, thats the basic and general programming style, why people gave a name now? Did i misunderstood it , please help me on this if possible

Comment: WebHooks are just another name for a specific implementation of callbacks or Event Listeners when these are executed via HTTP verbs. People give new names to old things all the time.

Comment: thanks @Mastacheata , thats what i thought and want to confirm the same from other users, i mean i didnt just get that when i heard for the first time, we have been using listeners since long and take action based on that from the beginning and now its via HTTP, thats the only difference which i found